# Detectar versión de android con Alloy y Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

Estoy haciendo una aplicación móvil con el framework Alloy Titamium de JavaScript, y quiero hacer un condición para que si el celular tiene una versión de android 5.0 ejecute una línea de código que programe; si no, si el celular tiene una versión 7.1, que haga otra cosa. Es decir, algo como esto:

```
if(android == 5.0){
    //-----code----
}else{
    if(android == 7.0){
        //-----code----------
    }
}
```

¿Es posible? ¿Cómo se haría?

Answer (score 0):

Si usas Titanium puedes obtener la versión mediante [**Titanium.Platform.version**](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Platform).

Ejemplo:

```
var app_version = Titanium.Platform.version; 

if (app_version == 5.0) { 
    //-----code----
}else{
    if(app_version == 7.0){
        //-----code----------
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: @JoseGonzales ya lo probaste, te sugiero revises la documentación ahí vienen todas las propiedades que puedes usar, saludos!

Comment: @ Jorgesys, si me fije en la documentacion gracias..!